# How to embed video on html that will not play on browser?

Tags: html

I know this question is simple and kind of silly but I really need to get an answer. I am doing some kind of family videos put together and I want that to be on one page or like an HTML file. but when I embed/link a directory file of video to the html it will play on the browser. Is there any way that when I embed a link it will just ask what application to open and will open on that video player that I selected? I'm not really that techie but I really need to make an offline HTML to organize my stuff. thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way that when i embed a link it will just ask what application to open and will open on that videoplayer that i selected

Not all browsers do this, but many will.  One way to look at this is that the browser in this case *is* the desired application for viewing that video.  (Often times, the user didn't make this choice of course, it was made for them.)

There are a couple ways around this.  One way is to add the `download` attribute to your anchor element:

```
<a href="video.webm" download>Download the video</a
```

This will suggest to the browser that the video should be saved to local disk, and not just immediately opened.

A second method is to use an M3U file.  All you need in your file is something like this:

```
#EXTM3U
https://example.com/video.webm
```

These tend to open up in the default player.  Just keep in mind that not everyone has such a player installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your video files downloadable by creating a download link to it. This will give the option of either open in browser or save to local disk.